# Java thread synchronize(The output cannot be stable)

Tags: java, multithreading

```
class hehe implements Runnable {

  static int count = 0;

  public synchronized void count() {
    count++;
  }

  public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      count();
    }
  }
}

public class Sychronise {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread a1 = new Thread(new hehe());
    Thread a2 = new Thread(new hehe());

    a1.start();
    a2.start();

    try {
      a1.join();
      a2.join();
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(hehe.count);
  }
}
```

The count should be 20000, but my output is still unstable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your synchronized does nothing as it's synchronizing on each individual 'hehe' instance.  To make it synchronize on the Class object (which owns the 'count' variable) make your count method static too:

```
public static synchronized void count(){
    count++;
}
```

Or synchronize on an object:

```
public class hehe implements Runnable {
    static int count= 0;
    static Object lock = new Object();

    public void count(){
        synchronized(lock) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    public void run(){
        for (int i=0;i<10000;i++){
            count();
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your count method is synchronized but there are 2 instances of the object Hehe, so each synchronization would be scoped to each instance, in this case I would suggest to use an [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)

First try with a static count method.

```
public static synchronized void count(){
    count++;
}

public void run(){
    for (int i=0;i<10000;i++){
        Hehe.count();
    }   
}
```

Comment: @Varrian You are welcome, please upvote and accept my answer.